# Не могу понять как вывести сообщение для тех кто не участвовал

Tags: python

```
   favorite_languages = {
      'jen' : 'python',
      'sarah' : 'c', 
      'edward' : 'Ruby's, 
      'phil' : 'python'
       }
    yhastniki = ['alex', 'jen', 
    'niko']
    for name in 
    favorite_languages.keys() 
         print(name.title()) 
         if name in yhastniki:
           print("Hi " + 
    name.title() + "spacious za 
    opros " 
  +favorite_languages[name].title()
```

#это вывод 'спасобо'для тех кто есть в словаре , не могу просто понять как прилепить сообщение для тех кто не участвовал, тоесть кого нет в словаре но есть в списке yhastniki. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: отформатируйте пожалуйста ваш код

Answer (score 1):

А давайте поспорим - вы даже не пытались запустить код, который сюда запостили. Иначе вы бы прибежали сюда с вопросами - а почему у меня в коде куча синтаксических ошибок? Ну, например,

```
'edward' : 'Ruby's,
```

отсутсиве двоеточия вот в этой конструкции

```
for name in 
    favorite_languages.keys()
```

Вообще-то это есть проявление прямого неуважения к тем, кому вы задаете вопрос. Я думаю, вам надо прочитать сначала пять страниц учебника, а потом писать программу. Тогда и таких детских вопросов не было бы. А уж изъясняться, что вам надо -этому учат в школе на уроках литературы.

Я так и не понял, что вы хотите.
Вот код, который выводит все всем:

```
favorite_languages = {
      'jen' : 'python',
      'sarah' : 'c', 
      'edward' : "Ruby's", 
      'phil' : 'python'
       }
yhastniki = ['alex', 'jen', 'niko']
for name in favorite_languages.keys(): 
     print(name.title()) 
     if name in yhastniki:
         print("Hi ", name.title(),"spacious za  opros ",favorite_languages[name].title())
     else:
         print ("Hi ", name.title(),'Илья не может прилепить что-то тем ухастникам, которые не участвуют')
```

Результат:

```
Jen
Hi Jen spacious za  opros Python
Sarah
Hi  Sarah Илья не может прилепить что-то тем ухастникам, которые не участвуют
Edward
Hi  Edward Илья не может прилепить что-то тем ухастникам, которые не участвуют
Phil
Hi  Phil Илья не может прилепить что-то тем ухастникам, которые не участвуют
```

Разбирайтесь.

Comment: Синтаксические ошибки только из ща того что с телефона пичптал весь код, который на ПК и сам код работает, я просто не понимал как прилепить * примите участие Niko или alex которые находятся в списке yhastniki .  И все .

Comment: А куда же вы так торопились, что не лень было код писать с телефона? А потом два дня не заглядывать в ответ. Но, надеюсь, теперь все понимаете. И ответ вам пригодился. И вы знаете, что при этом надо делать.